# 301 directory redirect on webconfig file .NET

Tags: .net, redirect

im trying to do a 301 redirect on a webconfig file for .net so that anything that has /Item/ in the URL redirects to /Product/

The following is not working, any suggestions greatly appreciated?

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="rule1">
      <match url="/Item/(.*)" />
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/Product//$1" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: "not working" - please explain. Is no redirect happening? Do you get a 302 redirect? Do you get an error? Something else?

Comment: The 301 redirect does not happen, it just stays on the same URL and the custom 404 error page is returned. I should have been more precise, im still new to .NET :)